# remote.origin.fetch - how is set by default, what it depends on and may it change without explicit git config?

Tags: git

Last time I struggled with problem that my `remote.origin.fetch` changed to empty value so that I couldn't operate on remote branches. When I resorted to clone remote repository again (as bare) it turned out that my `remote.origin.fetch` is empty by default(!). I have other remote bound with the same local and observed no issues with the second. (actually both of them have other aliases than "origin" but it probably doesn't matter here). 
`git fsck` didn't show any issues.

I see I don't understand something.

What determines `remote.origin.fetch` value when I'm cloning remote repo? May it depend (be forced by) on remote server setting (gerrit,bitbucket,gitlab,github)?

How remote.origin.fetch value may be changed in my local repo except with explicit `git config` command? May it happen during fetch or silently "under" other specific command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set when your remote is created, which happens automatically when you do your `git clone`. It's created along with `remote.origin.push` as part of the default remote creation process.

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) :

> **Showing Your Remotes**
>
> To see which remote servers you have configured, you can run the git remote command. It lists the shortnames of each remote handle you’ve specified. *If you’ve cloned your repository, you should at least see origin — that is the default name Git gives to the server you cloned from*

*(emphasis mine)*

So I guess the key point is the `--bare` cloning. **Bare repositories don't have remotes** set like non-bare ones.

The relevant passage in the `--bare` [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---bare) is

> Also the branch heads at the remote are copied directly to corresponding local branch heads, without mapping them to refs/remotes/origin/. When this option is used, neither remote-tracking branches **nor the related configuration variables are created**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint! I read more and I think I understand what is going on here but I cannot admit that I have any idea what is the purpose of this strategy used for bare cloning. Now I think that better alternative for working with many worktrees is normal clone with --no-checkout rather than bare cloning.